# Quick Sort Algorithm in Ruby - Stack Level Too Deep

Tags: ruby, quicksort

I am trying to implement a quick sort algorithm in Ruby. I got a simple one working pretty quickly but it involved creating temporary arrays on the fly. I'm trying to implement a more streamlined quick sort that only swaps elements in place without the need to create additional arrays.

Does anyone know why this code doesn't work? I've been following the pattern laid out [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLauY6PpjW4&list=PLI1t_8YX-ApvMthLj56t1Rf-Buio5Y8KL&index=7) in exact detail but I can't get it to work properly.

```
def quicksort(arr = [], left = 0, right = 0)
  right = arr.length - 1 if right < 1
  if left < right
    index = partition(arr, left, right)
    quicksort(arr, left, index - 1)
    quicksort(arr, index, right)
  end
  arr
end

def partition(arr, left, right)
  pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2]
  while left <= right
    left += 1 while arr[left] < pivot
    right -= 1 while arr[right] > pivot
    if left <= right
      arr[left], arr[right] = arr[right], arr[left]
      left += 1
      right -= 1
    end
  end
  left
end

arr = [8, 10, 13, 5, 6, 20, 2, 43, 9, 11, 15]
p quicksort(arr)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we throw a debugging `p "Left #{left}, Right #{right}`...

```
def quicksort(arr = [], left = 0, right = 0)
  right = arr.length - 1 if right < 1
  if left < right
    index = partition(arr, left, right)
    quicksort(arr, left, index - 1)
    ...
```

We find there's a problem. `left` is never set. It's always the default of 0. And right is doing its own thing.

```
"Left 0, Right 10"
"Left 0, Right 8"
"Left 0, Right 2"
"Left 0, Right 1"
"Left 0, Right 10"
"Left 0, Right 7"
"Left 0, Right 6"
"Left 0, Right 5"
"Left 0, Right 2"
"Left 0, Right 1"
"Left 0, Right 10"
"Left 0, Right 4"
"Left 0, Right 2"
"Left 0, Right 1"
"Left 0, Right 10"
"Left 0, Right 5"
"Left 0, Right 2"
"Left 0, Right 1"
"Left 0, Right 10"
"Left 0, Right 5"
"Left 0, Right 2"
"Left 0, Right 1"
```

The problem is `right = arr.length - 1 if right < 1`. If `right` is ever < 1 it's set back to the end of the array. `left` is always 0 so `left` is always less than `right`. `quicksort(arr, 0, index - 1)` is recursed into over and over again. `quicksort(arr, index, right)` is never reached.

---

Your `partition` is fine, and good eye noticing `pivot` can be calculated inside `pivot`.

What tripped you up is those defaults. You're setting a default for `right` any time it's less than 1. But it should only be set if it isn't passed in at all.

```
def quicksort(arr, left = 0, right = arr.length - 1)
  if left < right
    index = partition(arr, left, right)
    quicksort(arr, left, index - 1)
    quicksort(arr, index, right)
  end
  arr
end
```

Now `quicksort(array)` is equivalent to `quicksort(array, 0, array.length - 1)`. Subsequent recursive calls pass `left` and `right` in, so no need for defaults.

And no default for the array. If they forget to pass an array in that should be an [ArgumentError](https://ruby-doc.org/core/ArgumentError.html).

---

I prefer the public wrapper approach used in the video. If someone accidentally passes in too many arguments they get a clear ArgumentError rather than something weird happening.

```
# Using the ! convention for functions which alter their arguments.
def quicksort!(array)
  _quicksort!(array, 0, array.length - 1)
end

private def _quicksort!(array, left, right)
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If sorting large arrays, the stack space can be limited to O(log(n)), but worst case time complexity will remain at O(n^2). I don't know ruby syntax, but the ideal is to only recurse on the smaller partition, and loop back for the larger partition:

```
def quicksort(arr, left = 0, right = arr.length - 1)
  while left < right
    index = partition(arr, left, right)
    if((index - left) < (right-index))
        quicksort(arr, left, index - 1)
        left = index
    else
        quicksort(arr, index, right)
        right = index-1
  end
  arr
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print every step of quick sort you can do like this:

````
def advanced_quicksort(arr, low = 0, high = arr.length - 1)
    if low < high
        pivot_index = partition(arr, low, high)
        puts "[#{arr.join(', ')}]" #you can change it to ```puts arr.join(' ') else
        advanced_quicksort(arr, low, pivot_index - 1)
        advanced_quicksort(arr, pivot_index + 1, high)
    end
end

def partition(arr, low, high)
    pivot = arr[high]
    i = low - 1

    (low..high - 1).each do |j|
        if arr[j] < pivot
            i += 1
            arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
        end
    end

    arr[i + 1], arr[high] = arr[high], arr[i + 1]
    i + 1
end

# Example usage:
arr = [1, 3, 9, 8, 2, 7, 5]
puts "[#{arr.join(', ')}]"
advanced_quicksort(arr)
````